# JOptionPane inputs to array for mean

Tags: java, string, arraylist, mean, joptionpane

I am trying to make a grade book that takes the inputs of five assignments for X amount of students and comes up with a final grade for each student. The program successfully loops according to the number of students entered, and compiles correctly. However, I need to come up with the averages of each assignment based on the whole class. I'm trying to accomplish this with arrays, but I'm desperately stuck.

```
int numStudents = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number of students: "));
String[] examOneGrade = new String[numStudents];
String[] examTwoGrade = new String[numStudents];
String[] examFinalGrade = new String[numStudents];
String[] projectGrade = new String[numStudents];
String[] homeworkGrade = new String[numStudents];
// loops depending on number of students in the class
for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Student Name: ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Grades for " + name,
                " ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    examOneGrade[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Exam 1 Grade: ");
    examTwoGrade[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Exam 2 Grade: ");
    examFinalGrade[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Final Exam Grade: ");
    projectGrade[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Project Grade: ");
    homeworkGrade[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Homework Grade: ");
    // converts strings to floats
    float exam1 = Float.parseFloat(examOneGrade[i]);
    float exam2 = Float.parseFloat(examTwoGrade[i]);
    float finalExam = Float.parseFloat(examFinalGrade[i]);
    float project = Float.parseFloat(projectGrade[i]);
    float homework = Float.parseFloat(homeworkGrade[i]);
    // weights
    float number1 = exam1 * .10f;
    float number2 = exam2 * .10f;
    float number3 = finalExam * .30f;
    float number4 = project * .30f;
    float number5 = homework * .20f;
    // calculates student final grade
    float grade = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final Grade: " + grade,
                " " + name, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I'm not asking to be given the answer, I'm just desperate to know if I'm on the right path and where I should be looking. This exact topic seems to be nonexistent.

My attempt at a low grade method:

```
public int getMinimum(List<Student> studentList) {
float lowGrade = getExamOneGrade[0];
for(Student student : studentList) {
if(student.getExamOneGrade() < lowGrade) {
lowGrade = getExamOneGrade;
  }
}
return lowGrade;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically there's nothing wrong about your approach. But you should go one step further and put all the information and computations concerning a single student in an object. E.g.

Please note, that this is just a brief example. You have to complete it on your own.

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private float examOneGrade;
    private float examTwoGrade;
    private float examFinalGrade;
    private float projectGrade;
    private float homeworkGrade;

    // getters and setters

    public String getName(){
       return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
    }

    public float getExamOneGrade(){
       return examOneGrade;
    }

    public void setExamOneGrade(float examOneGrade) {
       this.examOneGrade = examOneGrade;
    }

    // and so on ...

    // weight computation goes here

    public float getExamOneWeight() {
       return examOneGrade * .10f;
    }

    public float getExamTwoWeight() {
       return examOneGrade * .10f;
    }

    // ...

    public float getFinalGrade {
        return getExamOneWeight() +
               getExamTwoWeight() +
               // ...
               getHomeworkWeight();
    }

}
```

Then in your code

```
int numStudents = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Enter number of students: "));

List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

// loops depending on number of students in the class
for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {

    Student student = new Student();

    student.setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Student Name: "));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Grades for " + student.getName(),
            " ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    student.setExamOneGrade(Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Exam 1 Grade: ")));
    student.setExamTwoGrade(Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Exam 2 Grade: ")));

    // and so on ..

    // now add the student to the ArrayList
    studentList.add(student);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final Grade: " + student.getFinalGrade(),
            " " + student.getName(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

**EDIT II:**

```
// show the averages here
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Avg Grade Of Exam One: " + getAverageGradeOfExamOne(studentList), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Avg Grade Of Exam Two: " + getAverageGradeOfExamTwo(studentList), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

// ...
```

Using this list of students you can now compute whatever you want and it is all well structured and easy to use.

e.g.

```
private float getAverageGradeOfExamOne(List<Student> studentList) {
   float sum;

   for(Student student : studentList){
      sum += student.getExamOneGrade();
   }

   return sum/studentList.size();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using this method above in your "original class" in the main-method we are talking about you could print the result this way:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Avg Grade Of Exam One: " + getAverageGradeOfExamOne(studentList), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

If this does not work I suppose your "main-method" is a static one. Then change getAverageGradeOfExamOne() to static too, like this

```
private static float getAverageGradeOfExamOne(List<Student> studentList) {
   float sum;

   for(Student student : studentList){
      sum += student.getExamOneGrade();
   }

   return sum/studentList.size();
}
```

One of these method declarations should tie up loose ends for you.

Comment: I won’t have the chance to work with this information until later today, but it looks great. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out. I attempted something like this but was missing quite a bit, this actually makes a lot of sense. But I wasn’t sure if the object portion should be built in the same class or another?

Comment: Disregard that stupid question please. But an actual question would be if that final bit to set up the average goes in the original class or the student class? And if it goes in the student class, how do I call to it?

Comment: When I add the average float to the Student class I get an error for studentList

Comment: "There is no stupid question, only stupid answers". ;)  The Student-class has to be put into its own Java-File. As long as this file is in the same package as your original class, there is no import-statement needed. You could define the Student-class as an inner class, though, but I wouldn't recommend it! It makes your code complicated and unreadable the more methods you implement into Student -- The average-method has to be put into the original class as this class possesses the list of Students you want to iterate through.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations. I know I'm probably missing something simple, but when I try adding the average method to the original class, I still get an error for studentList (cannot find symbol). I assume this is because the array list is inside of the static method, but I'm not sure how to connect them without them being in the same brackets.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I re-edited my post. Just hand in the studentList as a parameter when calling the method.

Comment: Brilliant! Like usual I tried something like that but had it wrong. Although you've already been too generous, I've got one more question if you please. When trying to print the result (I don't care if it's in a JOptionPane or not at this point) I get a ton of errors. I take it this has to be printed differently than the other methods?

Comment: I did another edit. Please have a look at the answer.

Comment: You are truly wonderful. I apologize for asking so much of you, but I truly learned a great deal. I'm not even worried about this last detail, as I am ecstatic with the results. But if I were to ask just one more tiny question (more for future reference), how would I get it to only print the average in the end, instead of after every student (I assume maybe another loop?)? But seriously, you were such a great help.

Comment: Your assumption is right. You have to call getAverageGradeOfExamOne() outside your "for-loop". But there is no other loop needed. The loop happens inside getAverageGradeOfExamOne(). Just call the method and hand in the studentList. I've re-edited my post again. Please have a look at EDIT II.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will ask no more of you. You are a saint!

Comment: Don't mention it. ;)